# How can I restrict one SFTP user to a single vhost, while allowing another user access to multiple?

Tags: permissions

I have several Apache virtualhosts in the standard location:

- /var/www/vhosts/example1.com/htdocs
- /var/www/vhosts/example2.com/htdocs
- /var/www/vhosts/example3.com/htdocs

These directories are owned by the user `www-data` and the group `www-data`, with permissions set to 770 (`drwxrwx---`).

I SFTP into these directories as `travis`, who is a member of the `www-data` group.

**Here is my challenge:** I would like to create a second SFTP user, named `chris`, who only has permission to access *one* of these directories (example3.com).

So I tried this:

- created a new group named `example3-www-data`
- gave the new group ownership of the webroot: `sudo chgrp -R example3-www-data /var/www/example3.com/htdocs`
- added the user `www-data` to `example3-www-data` as a secondary group (so Apache would have permission to read from the example3.com webroot)
- created a new user named `chris`, with `example3-www-data` as his primary group

So: `chris`' primary group has ownership of the `htdocs` directory, so he should be able to access it. And the `www-data` user also belongs to that group - so Apache should also be able to access the directory. Everything should work, right?

Nope! When I log in as `chris` (whether via SFTP or via the shell), I'm told that I don't have permission to access `/var/www/vhosts/example3.com/htdocs`.

Why is that? Is it because `chris` doesn't have access to the *parent* directories (e.g., `/var/www/vhosts`)? (I don't want to give him access to parent directories, if I can avoid it - remember, the whole point is to restrict his access to this one specific directory. I'd also prefer not to make this folder his home directory, because there will eventually be *multiple* such users who need the same access.)

**Basically: how can I arrange my users / groups / file permissions such that:**

- the user `travis` can upload files to all three webroots, *and*
- the user `chris` can *only* upload files to `/var/www/vhosts/example3.com/htdocs`, *and*
- Apache can read/write/execute files uploaded by either user, without the need to  manually adjust file permissions after uploading?

Sorry for the n00b question; I don't really understand how Linux file permissions are meant to be applied in situations like this. (Any general principles/tips/links in that area would be greatly appreciated.)

I doubt it matters, but I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: The point of running the web server as the www-data user and group is that this is an *unprivileged* user - the www-user user doesn't have *write* permission anywhere - this is a good security measure.  For this reason you shouldn't add users to this group, it's meant for daemons only.  Don't set file permissions to give this user or group write access to any files (in rare cases a web app might need it for *some* files).  Everything you want to do can be done by creating your own groups and adding users to those, not by re-using the www-data group which is not supposed to be used like this.

Comment: Thanks. Could you give me an example of what groups I would need to create, and how I would modify the permissions of the various webroot directories (if at all)?

Comment: I found the tutorial linked below, which explains how to grant users (e.g., my `chris` user) access to their own site directories. However, it *doesn't* explain how to grant another user (e.g., my `travis` user) access to *all* of the site directories.

http://www.virtualvcp.com/linux-technical-guides/195-apache-webserver-file-permissions-on-virtualhosts

Comment: Need to create a new group, add those users who should be able to edit all dirs, and add group write permissions to those files.  But to make sure new files they create are still editable by the group you need to do a fair bit.  Have a read of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12842/make-all-new-files-in-a-directory-accessible-to-a-group - you can use umask on those user's profiles - or the alternative is ACLs.  To me ACLs are probably more complexity than you want.  Sorry this is not a proper answer, and just a comment with some pointers.